# PHP: Uploading multiple images to imgur at once

Tags: php, api, imgur

I've got the following code and it works perfectly fine for uploading one image to Imgur using their API:

```
$client_id = $myClientId;
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    $url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json';
    $headers = array("Authorization: Client-ID $client_id");
    $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($file));

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL=> $url,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_POST => 1,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pvars
    ));

    $json_returned = curl_exec($curl); // blank response

    $json = json_decode($json_returned, true);

    curl_close ($curl);
```

However I need to upload multiple images at once. On the client side, the user will have multiple `<input type="file" />` fields. I'm completely stuck now with figuring out where and how I will need to modify this code in order to handle multiple image upload when they come through to the server in the form of an array. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the markup as follows:

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

Now, you can loop through the `$_FILES` array using a `foreach`, like so:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
    if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) )
    {
        // $tmpName is the file
        // code for sending the image to imgur
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking about creating a loop but I wanted to know whether there was a better way? For example if I understood correctly Imgur would allow multiple upload through their API right? And if so, wouldn't that option work far quicker then doing a one by one upload through a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @user1775598: have you looked at there API manual? As far as [I can see](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload), that is not possible with one call.

Comment: @user1775598: As Glavic said above, it isn't possible with one API call. The only way would be to loop through each file and then process them individually.

Comment: I was reading this https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album which made it sound like it was possible to send through an array of images and upload them all at once.

Comment: @user1775598: no, you can only assign multiple images, that are already uploaded on the server, to specific album.

Comment: @Glavić: Thanks for the edit, but could you clarify how is it invalid? The example I showed was from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Comment: Sorry to keep coming about it but could you explain what they mean by this then? https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album#album-add-to

I'm new to this but specifically i'm talking about the `Route`: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/{id}/add` part

Comment: @user1775598: That is for *moving* the already-uploaded images to a different album. You can't **upload** new images with that.

Comment: @AmalMurali: sorry, maybe my edit comment was inappropriated for that kind of edit. Your's/PHP's HTML is ok, if you need multiple `<input>`'s for one name `file[]`, where you can upload so many files as there are `<input>`'s. I thought OP needed multiple files selection on one field, that is unlimited files selection; that is why I edited; you can rollback the edit. Both cases are correct, it just depends what OP wants ;)

Comment: @Glavić: Yeah. Since the OP accepted this answer, I assume that's what he wanted. :)